# Segmentation fault(core dumped)How I rid this error?

Tags: c

I am trying to read 10 random words from the file using this code. While Dev-c can do this, it gives linux segmentation fault (core dumped) error. How do I get rid of this error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(){

    FILE* fp = NULL;
    char words[20];
    int i = 0 , ran = 0;
    int t;
    srand(time(NULL));
    fp = fopen("test.txt" , "r");
    for(t=0;t<10;t++){

        for(; fgets(words , sizeof(words) , fp) ; i++);

        ran = rand() % i;
        rewind(fp);
        for(i = 0 ; i < ran ; i++){
            fgets(words , sizeof(words) , fp);
        }

        printf("%s\n" , words);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check that `fopen()` succeeded.

Comment: Segmentation fault usually means dereferencing NULL pointer. Make sure `fp` is not NULL after `fopen`; print an error message (like `perror("can't open file")` or `printf("Can't open file: %d\n", errno)`) and exit otherwise.

Comment: This may be useful too: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You should be able to debug and find out alot more about your code than you have before having to resort to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the result of `fopen` like so:

```
    fp = fopen("test.txt" , "r");
    if(!fp)
    {
        perror("test.txt");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

And then ensure that `text.txt` exists in the same directory that you're running your program in.

`i` here will be the random number chosen in the last iteration of the enclosing loop:

```
for(; fgets(words , sizeof(words) , fp) ; i++);
```

I suggest setting `i=0` in the initialization section of this loop, so that you won't get EOF upon reading too many lines.